# four variables of $_GET not working with MYSQL

Tags: php, android, mysql

I tried this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from business WHERE ptype = '".$_GET["ptype"]."' AND state = '".$_GET["state"]."' AND city = '".$_GET["city"]."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

but if I don't put 3 GET's I get an error from MySql:

> localhost/get_allinfo.php?ptype=PUB&state=Center

Then I get a MySQL error

I tried this:
but it doesn't matter if I put "state" in URL `$_GET["ptype"]) & (isset($_GET["state"]))`

I get the result from "ptype" only

```
    if (isset($_GET["ptype"])) {
    $ptype = $_GET["ptype"];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from business WHERE ptype = '$ptype'") or die(mysql_error());

}elseif(isset($_GET["ptype"]) & (isset($_GET["state"]))){
    $ptype = $_GET["ptype"];
    $state = $_GET["state"];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from business WHERE ptype = '$ptype' and WHERE state = '$state") or die(mysql_error());
}else {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `business`") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Your script is probably vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should make it a bit more robust:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * from business';
$arrQueryString = array();
if(isset($_GET['ptype'])) $arrQueryString[] = 'ptype="'.$_GET['ptype'].'"';
if(isset($_GET['state'])) $arrQueryString[] = 'state="'.$_GET['state'].'"';
if(isset($_GET['city'])) $arrQueryString[] = 'city="'.$_GET['city'].'"';
$sql .= (count($arrQueryString)) ? ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ',$arrQueryString) : '';
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thank you sir! you are my hero!

Answer (score 0):

Following is wrong

```
SELECT * from business WHERE ptype = '$ptype' and WHERE state = '$state
```

It should be:

```
SELECT * from business WHERE ptype = '$ptype' AND state = '$state'
```

Look up documentation on WHERE and add a ending quote to $state

Also change placement of your if conditions

```
if(isset($_GET["ptype"]) & (isset($_GET["state"]))){
$ptype = $_GET["ptype"];
$state = $_GET["state"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from business WHERE ptype = '$ptype' AND state = '$state'") or die(mysql_error());
}elseif (isset($_GET["ptype"])) {
$ptype = $_GET["ptype"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from business WHERE ptype = '$ptype'") or die(mysql_error());

}if(isset($_GET["ptype"]) & (isset($_GET["state"]))){
$ptype = $_GET["ptype"];
$state = $_GET["state"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from business WHERE ptype = '$ptype' and WHERE state = '$state") or die(mysql_error());
}else {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `business`") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Your ptype is always set, and that means your control always goes in 1st if statement. Even if state is set.

PS. learn about PDO/mysqli, you wont regret it.

Comment: Thank you sir but its keep showing result for all "ptype" i want to it to show "ptype" that have the right "state"

Comment: I edited my answer, this should work